# Creating Dataframe from tokenized dictionary and bow

Tags: dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe from tokenized dictionary and bag of words. I have shared the notebook via my [GitHub](https://github.com/BradfordMutemi/DataFrame_Creation).

After trying, you can see the dataframe I created while the expected dataframe is also shown.

I will highly appreciate your assistance.